Business Central SetTableView with temporary table doesn't apply filters
I am trying to populate list with filtered records in temporary table. Records in temp table are stored and counted properly. But when page is open all records from original table are displayed.
    procedure DrillDown_Cust_Retail_Open()
var
    CustomerLedgerEntry: Record "Cust. Ledger Entry";
    TempCustomerLedgerEntries: Record "Cust. Ledger Entry" temporary;
    CustomerLedgerPage: Page "Customer Ledger Entries";
begin
    // Reset records and apply initial filter
    CustomerLedgerEntry.Reset();
    CustomerLedgerEntry.SetRange("Open", true);

    // Fetch and insert filtered records into the temporary table
    if CustomerLedgerEntry.FindSet() then begin
        repeat
            TempCustomerLedgerEntries := CustomerLedgerEntry;
            TempCustomerLedgerEntries.Insert();
        until CustomerLedgerEntry.Next() = 0;
    end;

    // Confirm filtered records
    Message('Filtered records count: %1', TempCustomerLedgerEntries.Count());

    // Verify that the temporary table contains the correct records before opening the page
    if TempCustomerLedgerEntries.FindSet() then begin


    end else begin
        Message('No records found');
    end;
    // Set the table view to the temporary records
    CustomerLedgerPage.SetTableView(TempCustomerLedgerEntries);
    Message('Opening page with filtered records.');
    CustomerLedgerPage.Run();
end;


SetTableView only copies the current View you have set on the record meaning filters, sorting etc. corresponding to calling the GetView and SetView procedures on a record variable.
It is not a reference to the actual temporary instance of the table.
You could try running the page on the record instead:
Page.Run(Page::"Customer Ledger Entries", TempCustomerLedgerEntries);


Thank You very much. You saved me hours.
